# How to make a PayPal payment between 2 clients?

Tags: android, node.js, paypal, payment-gateway

I don't have a great idea on how PayPal works and I'm working on an android app ( using Nodejs for backend )   where customers sell and buy products from each other ( a market place ) .

For example :

Customer A is selling a product

Customer B is going to buy the product that A is selling and going to pay him using PayPal .

How can I make  this transaction happen and make sure the money goes to A .